# Chrome extension asynchronous messaging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, messaging

I am currently working on a Chrome extension and I want to do the following.

content.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "Teszt", licenseKey: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX", data: "bolond"}, (response) => {
        alert(response.data);
});
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if(request) {

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", `https://api.hyper.co/v4/licenses/${request.licenseKey}`);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer publickey`)

        xhr.onload = () => {
            sendResponse({ sender: "background.js", data: (request.data+" response")  })
        }

        xhr.send();
    }
});
```

It doesn't return anything, obviously because a request needs time to be done.
How can I make it async? Or at least how to make content.js to wait until background actually returns something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the `simple one-time requests` section in the following documentation
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

> If you want to asynchronously use sendResponse, add return true; to
> the onMessage event handler.

Please try the following code. It should work

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if(request) {

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", `https://api.hyper.co/v4/licenses/${request.licenseKey}`);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer publickey`)

        xhr.onload = () => {
            sendResponse({ sender: "background.js", data: (request.data+" response")  })
        }

        xhr.send();
        return true;
    }
});
```